# Adding a list to a dictionary in a nested for loop with Python

Tags: python, json, boto3

I currently have the code

```
 for security_group in response["SecurityGroups"]:
        thing1 = security_group["something"]
        thing2= security_group["something2"]
        SG_list.append({
            "thing1": thing1,
            "thing2": "thing2",

        })
        #I want to add the below data that I get to the above dictionary "SG_list" but put the dictionaries in as a list of dictionaries into "SG_list"
        #accessing a nested element in the data structure
        for dictlist in security_group["IpPermissions"]:
            otherthing = dictlist["IpProtocol"]

            #another nested element inside the above nested element    
            for cidrIp in dictlist["IpRanges"]:
                source = cidrIp["CidrIp"]
                #append all the nested data to a dictionary
                SG_list.append({
                "Type": "Missing?",
                "Protocol": ipProtocol,
                "Port Range": portRange,
                "Source":source
                })
return SG_list
```

The code runs and outputs a big list full of dictionaries. However I am wanting to append the data from the two nested for loops to each page of data that I get from

`for security_group in response["SecurityGroups"]:`

for example I am wanting to get output that looks like,

```
{
    "Account ID": "123456789",
    "Region": "TODO",
    "SGName": "name",
    "SGId": "sg-1234567",
    "VpcId": "vpc-1234567",
    "List of more data":["thing1":data,"thing2":data]
  }
```

but instead my data is coming out as a new dictionary like

```
{
    "Account ID": "123456789",
    "Region": "TODO",
    "SGName": "launch-wizard-27",
    "SGId": "sg-123467",
    "VpcId": "vpc-1234567"
  },
 {
  "thing1": data,
  "thing2": data
 }
```

So in my output using

```
                    SG_list[0].update({
                    "Type": "Missing?",
                    "Protocol": ipProtocol,
                    "Port Range": portRange,
                    "Source":source
                    })
```

I get one big dictionary of all the data like,

```
[
  {
    "Account ID": "123456789",
    "Region": "TODO",
    "SGName": "SGname",
    "SGId": "sg-1234567",
    "VpcId": "vpc-1234567",
    "Protocol": "tcp",
    "Port Range": 1234
  },
```

however I am wanting

```
[
  {
    "Account ID": "123456789",
    "Region": "TODO",
    "SGName": "SGname",
    "SGId": "sg-1234567",
    "VpcId": "vpc-1234567",
    ["Type": "Missing?","Protocol": "tcp","Port Range": 1234]
  },
```

Comment: Your format: `["thing1":data,"thing2":data]` is invalid, you can't have key/value pairs in a list like that, only as `["thing1", data, "thing2", data]`..  The best you could do is `[{"thing1":data},{"thing2":data}]`, i.e. have a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, so how would I instead of doing `SG_list.append({
                "Type": "Missing?",
                "Protocol": ipProtocol,
                "Port Range": portRange,
                "Source":source
                })` at the end of the code, save that data as its own list, and then append that list to "SG_list"?

Answer (score 0):

so you want the loops to add the dictionaries to each other instead of getting a list of dictionaries, right?

in that case you just need to `update` the original dictionary that is already there with a new dictionary instead of append.

so if your list have the original dictionary in index 0, do something like

`SG_list[0].update({'New':'dic'})`

to be more clear. put this in the last loop and your original one will be updated.

```
            SG_list[0].update({
            "Type": "Missing?",
            "Protocol": ipProtocol,
            "Port Range": portRange,
            "Source":source
            })
```

Comment: Thank you! That is closer to what I am wanting being that I now have all the information in one dictionary, however is it possible to get the data that we .updated into a list inside of the dictionary?

Comment: could you add an example? I really didn't get what you want to do

Comment: I added in more in the original question due to limited comment characters

Comment: No, That isn't possible. but you could make a new dic key and add the new dictionary as the value in form of a tuple.

Comment: ```SG_list[0].update({'NewDic': {
                    "Type": "Missing?",
                    "Protocol": ipProtocol,
                    "Port Range": portRange,
                    "Source":source
                    }.items()})```

here is the code for it.
If that answered your question, better mark it as an answered.